# Creating multiple list from loops

Tags: python

I want to make multiple lists with my for loops, My code is:

```
  for port in portlist1:
    print port.getname(),port.getsize()
    for register in port.getregisters():
        j=j+1
    print j
    j=0
```

Output is:

```
  B 10
  1
  C 15
  1
  F 30
  1
```

I want to make list every time:

```
List1=[[B,10],1]
List2=[[C,15],1]
List3=[[F,30],1]
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: So essentially you want your output formatted differently?

Comment: Use list comprehensions: `[ [[p.getname(),p.getsize()],len(p.getregisters())] for p in portlist1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
lists = []
for port in portlist1:
    l = [[port.getname(), port.getsize()]]
    for register in port.getregisters():
        j=j+1
    l.append(j)
    lists.append(l)
    j=0
```

Comment: Inline as suggested by *alecxe* or using generator makes code much, much faster than your variant with multiple lookup overheads like `l.append`. BTW, `j=j+1` = lol. --> `j+=1`

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what was the value of `j` before the loop, but it looks like you are using it to measure the length of `port.getregisters()`. Try this one-liner:

```
result = [[[port.getname(), port.getsize()], len(port.getregisters())] for port in portlist1]
```

Comment: missing close paren on `len()` call

Comment: @alecxe Да пожалуйста! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to make a new list each time, you should just go with nesting each list. If the amount of ports is static, you can use `vars()['listX']`.. But still not really recomended. You should go with the answer given by `kroolik` or `alecxe`

But if you REALLY need someting like..:

```
List1=[[B,10],1]
List2=[[C,15],1]
List3=[[F,30],1]
```

You can use:

```
lname = "list"
for i,p in enumerate(portlist1):
    j = len(p.getregisters())
    vars()[lname+str(i)] = [(p.getname(),p.getsize()), j]

print list0
print list1
print list2
```

Comment: `vars()[lname+str(i)]` is unpythonic

Comment: @akaRem : It's not like I recommended it, I just answered his question: _«Creating multiple list from loops»_

Comment: It really looks like you recommend it for solving this problem.. Uh.

Comment: @akaRem, read it again: "But still not really recomended. You should go with the answer given by kroolik or alecxe". I answered the question, where he ASKED to have diffrent lists as output "I want to make list every time:*example given*".

Comment: "I want to make list every time" -> Use `yield` which is fast and memory-safe.. But I'll stop pushing. ;)

Comment: @akaRem: You could add an answer with your recomendation. I simply pushed out an answer which corresponds to _given example_. I hope that next time we "meet", you would have read the whole thread, and my post before you jump to critizism.

Comment: I *absolutely* agree with alecxe's answer. So I didn't make duplicates.